How to infer parameter types for a wrapping function in Typescript
I need to wrap functions and pass in the wrapped-functions' arguments as parameters in the wrapping-functions. Rather than create interfaces for arguments for each instance of wrapped functions, I was trying to create a type that infers this using generic types, however I end up with a tuple type that cannot be spread into the wrapped-function.
From what I have right now, is there a way I can achieve this in typescript?
I've tried the following

/**
 * Model instances
 * @description These are the instances of the models that will be used to interact with the database.
 */
const models = {
    session: Session(prisma.session),
    user: User(prisma.user)
}


/**
* A type for the arguments of resolver functions
*/
type ModelArguments<
    M extends keyof typeof models,
    T extends keyof {
        [P in keyof typeof models[M] as (
            typeof models[M][P] extends Function ? P : never
        )] : never
    }
> = Parameters<typeof models[M][T]>



/**
 * GraphQL resolvers
 * @description This is the object that will contain the resolvers for the queries defined in the schema.
 */
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        // session: async (p, args: ModelArguments<"session", "get">) => await models.session.get(),
        // user_sessions: async (p, args: ModelArguments<"session", "getByUser">) => await models.session.getByUser(),
        user: async (p, args: ModelArguments<"user", "get">) => {
            console.log(args); // {"userID": "<user-id>"}
            return await models.user.get(args.userID) // TS2339: Property userID does not exist on type [userID?: string]
        }
    },
};


However on the return line for resolvers.Query.user (for args) I get the Typescript error TS2339: Property userID does not exist on type [userID?: string] and I'm not sure how this is possible where console.log(args) is {userId?: "<user-id>"}

Parameters type constructs a tuple type of function parameters, args is
an array, in case of your user function, it's the tuple type of get function parameters, which is inside the models.user object, thus it should be accessed by numeric or string index models.user.get(args[0]) or as a global case models.user["methodName"](...args)

Thanks @HairyHandKerchief23, however whilst I can seemingly do console.log(args["userID"]) and get a result, I can't spread this, for example
writing { userID } I get: TS2339: Property userID does not exist on type [userID?: string]
and writing models.user.get(...args) I get: Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function at runtime. Additionally console.log(args[0]) returns undefined.
Do you know why this happens and how I can spread from this type?

Edit At runtime args is actually an object, which could explain the issue, however I don't know how to convert the Parameters tuple type to an object. Tried wrapping it as Omit<Parameters<typeof models[M][T]>, any[]> (and Pick) but this left it with no typings

The TS2339 error is likely because of typescript's type checking, sometimes typescript does not know how things behave in runtime.
I've searched about converting Parameters tuple type to an object type, the problem doesn't seem to have a solution, according to the answer in Get function parameter names and types in TypeScript , tuple type can't be converted to string literal types, thus you can't map parameter names inside a tuple.
Also tuples being objects in runtime is new to me.

Perhaps the problem is the source of args, where are they coming from? if args are passed at runtime as an object then the error is expected.

@HairyHandKerchief23 they are passed as an object at runtime, and the args are passed in by Apollo Server (which is routing the graphql requests to these resolvers). Thanks for your help. Looks like I'll have to aim to write some less-intelligent Typescript unless a way to convert to an object / another way to fetch parameter types appears.
